# Guardar valor de una variable

Tags: java, variables, sum

Estoy haciendo un proyecto sobre un inventario y trato de guardar el valor de una variable una vez se termine pero el problema es que tengo que inicializar la variables pUno , pDos, pTres, pCuatro y pCinco con algún valor y cuando se vuelve a correr el programa este no guarda el valor que introduje porque toma de nuevo el de la inicialización, hay alguna forma de guardar ese valor?

Dejo abajo el código que estoy desarrollando *lo comentado es porque no se ha desarrollado todavía*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menuPrincipal;
    int inventario;
    /*int clientes;
    String nombre;
    float cedula;*/
    float codigo;
    int suma;
    menuPrincipal = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor:\n Presione 1 si desea ingresar a la base de datos  "
            + "Inventario \n Presione 9 si desea ingresar a la base de datos Clientes: "));
    //ingresamos a Inventario
    if (menuPrincipal == 1) {
        inventario = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor:\n"
                + "Presione 1 si desea agregar prendas al inventario \n"
                + "Presione 2 si desea eliminar prendas del inventario"));

        //Agregar al inventario
        if (inventario == 1) {
            codigo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor seleccione la prenda que desea agregar: \n"
                    + "1 = pUno \n"
                    + "2 = pDos \n"
                    + "3 = pTres \n"
                    + "4 = pCuatro \n"
                    + "5 = pCinco "));
            int pUno = 0;
            /*int pDos = 0;
            int pTres = 0;
            int pCuatro = 0;
            int pCinco = 0;*/

            if (codigo == 1) {
                suma = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de prendas que desea agregar: "));
                pUno = pUno + suma;
            }
            /*if (codigo == 2) {
                pDos = pDos + 1;
            }
            if (codigo == 3) {
                pTres = pTres + 1;
            }
            if (codigo == 4) {
                pCuatro = pCuatro + 1;
            }
            if (codigo == 5) {
                pCinco = pCinco + 1;
            }*/
            System.out.print("El inventario actual es: \n"
                    + "pUno: " + pUno /*+ "\n"
                    + "pDos: " + pDos + "\n"
                    + "pTres: " + pTres + "\n"
                    + "pCuatro: " + pCuatro + "\n"
                    + "pCinco: " + pCinco + "\n"*/);

        }

        //Eliminar del inventario
        /*if (inventario == 2) {

        }*/

    }
    //Ingresanos a Clientes
    /*if (menuPrincipal = 9) {
    }*/}
```

Comment: Poniendo la palabra clave [static](https://www.ecodeup.com/metodos-variables-y-bloques-static-en-java-con-ejemplos/) antes del tipo de variables he iniciandola de una vez: `static int[] p={0,0,0,0};`. Nota: Al poner variables con nombles: `p1,p2,p3` o numbre así: `pUno,pDos,pTres` y que sean del mismo tipo de datos es una mala practica, en lugar de eso puedes usar un array mas util: `int[] p=new int[5]`, no solo es mas eficiente te quita la carga de escribir muchas variables llamada `pS` y te ofrecerá la posibilidad de usar bucles para modificarlo de forma facil.

Comment: [array](https://javadesdecero.es/arrays/unidimensionales-multidimensionales/)

Comment: No leí bien la pregunta, No se puede hacer lo que quieres, pero puedes crear y usar archivos para lograrlo: Te aconsejo usar el formato `JSON` para ello: convierte los contenido de la matris `p` en un `String` JSON:`String json_="{\"prendas\":{"; json+=p[0]; for ( int i=1; i<p.length; i++ ) {json_+=","+p[i];} json_+="} }";` y escribes el string en un archivo. Ya cuando se inicie el programa intenta leer el archivo y usa la biblioteca de Java para transformar el string en la matris que necesitas. Recuerda, puede ocurrir un error al leer el archivo y si eso pasa debes inicializar la matris en 0.

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es que las variables pUno(voy a cambiarla para seguir el consejo de buenas practicas) y las demás guarden un entero y no un string para llevarlo como control de cantidad disponible y también después agregarle después una opción para restar, entonces lo que ocupo es que en la variable se me guarden los valores int para llevar ese control, tipo base de datos.

Comment: Para lograrlo a juro debes crear un archivo y tambien leerlo. Si quieres tambien puedes alterar tu propio código java sobreescribiendo el código fuente(No te lo recomiendo) lp que tambien significa sobrescribir el mismo archivo java,

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

¡Felicidades!, la idea que has tenido es lo que ha llevado a lo que en el mundo de java se conoce como servidores de aplicaciones y a los tipos de almacenamiento.

### la memoria

Cuando creas una variable, de hecho estás ya usando un tipo de almacenamiento, el almacenamiento en memoria. Este tipo de almacenamiento muchas veces lo damos por sentado porque las computadoras actuales tienen mucha memoria, y lenguajes con administración automática de memoria como Java nos permiten hacer un mejor uso. La mayor ventaja del almacenamiento en memoria es que es muy rápido comparado con otros tipos de almacenamiento, incluso en tu computadora hay algunos tipos de memorias de mayor velocidad, algunos procesadores vienen con una memoria cache, etc.

Cuando corre la máquina virtual de java genera algo llamado caja de arena, que permite delimitar lo que ejecutas y tener una cantidad de memoria disponible para tus programas en Java, y curiosamente uno de los enemigos de su buen uso es el `System.exit`, porque esta instrucción mata a la máquina virtual.

Para hacer lo que estás pensando necesitas para empezar dejar a la máquina virtual de java corriendo todo el tiempo. Ahora el segundo problema es que las variables que te permiten usar memoria en Java tienen un ámbito para que no tengas que preocuparte con la libreación de memoria, así que cada que termina la ejecución de tu método main, lo que hayas almacenado en tus variables se borra, y para evitarlo tienes una infinidad de estrategias, entre las qe me gustaría destacar....

### hacer que tu programa nunca termine

suena alocado, y lo es en cierto sentido porque necesitas usar un ciclo infinito para que tu programa pueda correr infinitamente. Si no termina tu programa, no se borran las variables. Muchos se escandalizarán cuando lean esto, pero de hecho el tener un ciclo infinito o ciclo de control o ciclo principal del programa como se le conoce en muchos ámbitos te permitirá tener a tu disposición siempre el sistema. La forma más extrema creo son los servidores de aplicaciones, que están optimizados para correr cientos de aplicaciones al mismo tiempo y tienen la capacidad de conectarse con otros servidores en la misma u otras máquinas reales o virtuales para formar un [cluster](/questions/tagged/cluster) con la idea de distribuir el trabajo entre todos ellos. Ejemplos de servidores especializados para correr aplicaciones java hay muchos, por mencionar algunos: [tomee](/questions/tagged/tomee), [websphere](/questions/tagged/websphere), [payara](/questions/tagged/payara), [glassfish](/questions/tagged/glassfish), [pivotal](/questions/tagged/pivotal), [jboss](/questions/tagged/jboss), [wildfly](/questions/tagged/wildfly), [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat).

### persistir

En Java se le conoce como persistir o serializar a almacenar la información en un tipo de almacenamiento relativamente persistente, o al menos que te evite el problema del almacenamiento en memoria que es que si se va a la luz se pierde todo. La solución más elemental desde que los sistemas tipo [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) dominaron le mercado ha sido guardar información en [archivo](/questions/tagged/archivo), en este tipo de sistemas todo es un archivos. Hay dos grandes categorías de archivos, aquellos que son de texto o humanamente legibles y aquellos que son binarios o hechos para la computadora.
Existen varios modos de abrirlos y escribirlos, cosa de lo cual en Java prácticamente nunca te preocupas, pero para darte idea se pueden poner los modos para leer, leer y escribir, solo escribir, y escribir al final. Para el caso de los binarios puedes tener un tipo muy interesante que son los de acceso aleatorio pensados para que saltes de objeto en objeto dentro del archivo sin necesidad de leerlo completo. Con el tiempo el manejo de archivos se ha especializado al grado de que varios desarrollaron un tipo de archivo que te permitía comprimir la cantidad de información pero pudiendo accederla rápidamente, incluso usando lenguajes declarativos para poder buscar datos dentro de esos archivos. A estos sistemas para gestionar esos archivos y a veces a esos archivos o carpetas con esos archivos se les empezó a llamar base de datos, y a los programas especializados en ellos sistemas gestores de bases de datos. Existen varios tipos de bases de datos, como bases de datos lógicas, bases de datos relacionales, bases de datos no relacionales, etc. Algunos ejemplos de bases de datos que sé que se pueden usar con Java son [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), [db2](/questions/tagged/db2), [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), [derby](/questions/tagged/derby), [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra), [memsql](/questions/tagged/memsql), [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase), [access](/questions/tagged/access)

### Lo mejor de dos mundos

También hayalgunas bases de datos en memoria, es decir que en vez de guardar en archivos almacenan en la memoria directamente para permitirte aumentar la velocidad de transacciones de manera dramática, algunos ejemplos de este tipo de sistemas compatibles con java son: [h2](/questions/tagged/h2), [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)

### el futuro es ahora

ahora el problema muchas veces no es tanto como guardar información sino que vas a guardar, y para qué, por ello los grandes servicios en la nube proveen varios tipos de almacenamiento para atender a varias necesidades, un servicio muy popular recientemente ha sido [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore), pero como digo depende que quieras guardar, todo un sistema de ficheros, imágenes de máquinas virtuales, archivos que se van a leer frecuentemente, cosas que se van a leer relativamente frecuentemente, cosas que prácticamente nunca se van a leer, multimedia, cosas que necesitas *versionar*, etc. Explicarte de todo esto va más allá del ámbito de esta pregunta, pero igual quise mencionarlo en caso de que sea de tu interés.

Ahora que tienes una idea del increíble mundo de posibilidades te recomiendo que intentes de alguna manera de las muchas que te he compartido y si tienes algún problema nos lo compartas para poder seguir contribuyendo con nuestro conocimiento a tí y al resto de la comunidad.

Comment: Otro buen ejemplo de un bucle infinito son los juegos. Gracias por la respuesta fué muy interesante.